# How to batch convert timestamp to human date in filename?

Tags: bash, sed, unix-timestamp, date-formatting, file-rename

I have a set of files with the following filename format `<epochtimestamp>.topic-of-post.md`, for example `1436310000.server-3-2-1.md`.

I need to batch convert the timestamp part to human readable date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, example `2014-10-14.token-revocation.md`

How could I go about automating this process on a Windows system? I have Cygwin installed and some basic knowledge of bash scripting.

Comment: Welcom to SO. What `bash` version do you have in your Cygwin installation ?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome, it is `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Perl `rename` command, you can do

```
rename 'use Time::Piece; s/(^\d+)/my $t = localtime($1); $t->ymd/e' [0-9]*.md
```

Answer (score 0):

If it matters, the epoch stamp you gave doesn't match the date you used.

```
$: date -d@1436310000 +'%Y-%m-%d'
2015-07-07
```

Loop through each file, slice out the epoch, convert to the new format, then rename it. Show us what you tried if it gives you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
   # Get each file under the current directory 
   for f in *.md; 
    do 
      # Get the date portion of the file name
      orig_date=$(echo "${f%%.*}"); 
      # convert it to a human readable format
      cnv_date="$(date -d@$orig_date +%Y-%m-%H)"; 
      # rename
      rename "${orig_date}.server-3-2-1" "${cnv_date}.token-revocation" $f;  
    done
```

This works for me on a `GNU bash-4.2.26` and `rename-2.23.2`

If you don't have `rename`, you can use the `mv` command.

```
mv  "${orig_date}.server-3-2-1.md" "${cnv_date}.token-revocation.md"
```

or

```
mv "$f" "${cnv_date}.token-revocation.md"
```

Comment: My rename version is `rename from util-linux 2.25.2`.
My follow up question is how would I approach this without having to enter each file's name or "portion" after the date separated with a `.`?